# Initializing static data member from non-static member

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to initialize a static member variable from a sizeof of a non-static:

```
class Myclass
{
   int a;
   static const int b = sizeof(a);
};
```

This should be legal with c++11, right? It gives me compiler error C2327 ("a is no typename not static and no enumerator).

Compiler is Visual Studio 2015 Express.

Comment: `sizeof (Myclass::a)` should solve your problem.

Comment: @Jarod42 Er. Did you even try it? [rextexter](http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual) is your friend. It works in the [latest build of VC++](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) though so it looked to be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

This is obviously a bug in VC++, as in 19.00.23506, `sizeof(Myclass::a)` doesn't work. This seems to have been fixed somewhere between versions 19.00.23506 (try online [rextester](http://rextester.com/main)) and 19.00.23720.0 (try online [Microsoft](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/)). You may try to report the [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) or download a newer build of the IDE/compiler.

Still, I would report a bug anyways since the nested name specifier shouldn't be required.

Comment: Can you recommend me a workaround that can be implemented in short time?

Comment: Are there any updates for Visual Studio Express 2015 that go beyond version 14.0.50616.0 ? I cannot use the community edition for licensing reasons.